# Is OTA configuration supported by Android OS?

Tags: android, configuration, mobile-phones

I would like to know if the Android handsets can be configured Over-The-Air; in other words, if they can be configured for settings (such as GPRS , WAP or MMS ...) using OTA.

If yes, do they support OMA CP provisioning? Is there an XML example that can be used to configure the Android devices?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In order to send APN settings configuration SMS to terminals you need to maintain TAC based device database which supports OMA Client Provisioning, Ericsson/Nokia configuration and vendor proprietary Non OTA terminal settings specifications. If we put OMA CP aside which trying to make it in standard way, this area is very vendor specific and not fully open to public.

Besides terminal database, you would need SMPP connection and location middleware which listens location updates from mobile network to trigger setting SMS to terminal when it attaches the network. Basically flow would be something like

- Location middleware captures IMEI and MSISDN from location update data
- Using the TAC part of IMEI it queries the terminal database, terminal database returns the configuration setting as binary payload
- Messaging module prepares binary SMS by setting data coding scheme and UDH mask and put binary payload in short message area with UDH header
- Messaging module submits prepared binary SMS to SMSC for the delivery

Yes, OTA configuration is supported by Android OS, most of Android devices support OMA client provisioning.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the system build creator's signing keys you can create an OTA system update with arbitrary settings baked into it.

You can also create an application which adjusts anything that application has permission to adjust in response to traffic exchanged with a network server.  If the application is signed with the system certificate, it can have permissions to adjust a lot of things.  Otherwise, the permissions it can request are limited.